# PyQt add widget to second window

Tags: python, pyqt

I've got the following python code which opens a second window.  I can't figure out how to add a label or pushbutton to this second window.  I thought it would be easy but nothing I try seems to work.  Thanks!

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        menu = self.menuBar().addMenu(self.tr('View'))
        action = menu.addAction(self.tr('New Window'))
        action.triggered.connect(self.handleNewWindow)


    def handleNewWindow(self):
        window = QtGui.QMainWindow(self)
        window.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        window.setWindowTitle(self.tr('New Window'))

        window.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(300, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

If the two windows are different, it makes more sense to create two class.
 I guess the second one doesn't need to be a `QMainWindow` (= it doesn't need a menu and a toolbar and a status bar etc), so let's just make it a `QWidget`.

```
class SecondWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)

        self.button=QtGui.QPushButton("my button !")

        layout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.show()
```

In your main window, you cretae and instance of the class `SecondWindow`:

```
class FirstWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        ...
        self.show()

    def handleNewWindow(self):
        self.childWindow = SecondWindow(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a `TopLevel` window, using `QtGui.QDialog` seems to be more appropriate. To add button and label, you can do something like this:

```
def handleNewWindow(self):
        window = QtGui.QMainWindow(self)       
        window.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        window.setWindowTitle(self.tr('New Window'))

        button = QtGui.QPushButton("MY BUTTON!") #create button
        label = QtGui.QLabel("MY LABEL!") # create label
        CentralWidget = QtGui.QWidget() # create an empty widget
        CentralWidgetLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout() # create a layout
        CentralWidgetLayout.addWidget(label) # add your label to the layout
        CentralWidgetLayout.addWidget(button) # add your button to the layout
        CentralWidget.setLayout(CentralWidgetLayout) # assign your layout to the empty widget
        window.setCentralWidget(CentralWidget) #make the assigned widget CentralWidget

        window.show()
```